# object fit cover causing jagged edges in image when scaled down

Tags: css

```css
section.cover .parent {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red
}

section.cover img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

section.original {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="cover">
  <div class='parent'>
    <img src="https://brooklynbookfestival.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/Shawn-Harris.jpg" alt>
  </div>
 
</section>

<section class="original">
  <div>
    <img src="https://brooklynbookfestival.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/Shawn-Harris.jpg" alt>
  </div>
 
</section>
```

I'm using object fit cover in css and noticing when the image is scaled down to a small size it renders as jagged.

```
 <div alignItems="center">
   <div width='40px' height='40px'>
    <img
      className='img'
      src={url}
    />
  </div>
 </div>
```

**css**

```
.img { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Is there some way to prevent the image from becoming jagged when it scales down.
Original image size is 360 x 480

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you please add the entire code with HTML?

Comment: What is the image size and also share a screenshot of the jagged image.

Comment: Image size is 300 x 400.

Comment: At that size it should not have jagged edges even when scaling down. Share a screenshot please. You can blur some portions if it's personal image.

Comment: @AniketPandey
Added a screen shot of the image when it is set to cover and parent has a fixed width and height. The original image size is 360 x 480 I was incorrect above.

Comment: I'm pretty sure img tag does not have `objectFit` attribute.

Comment: The border will not be jagged if you have `border-radius:50%;` as it does not depend on the image. Also, downsizing an image should not cause such pixelation. How does your original image look?

Comment: Please add example or image to show the desired behaviour and also the current output. Also, include the steps you took for debugging up till now.

Comment: I also, noticed that use used `src={ }` which means you are using a framework, I guess. You have not mentioned that anywhere or shared any code which shows us your setup

Comment: React. I have debugged multiple images from online. Original image from online in post

Comment: I just added a code snippet using plain html and css and you can see the same jagged rendering happening.

Comment: Here's a minimal reproducible example that shows this issue: `<img style="width: 40px; height: 40px; object-fit: cover;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojz2t.jpg">`

Comment: @TimR did you ever figure out the cause of this ?

Comment: @me-me No, I could only verify that it can be reproduced independentent of your code. I can only compare the result to using a graphics editor to scale/resize the image with no interpolation instead of linear or cubic.